# about struct array as parameter compiled by gcc and vc

Tags: c, parameters, struct

I know that I can use struct array as function parameter like this

create a struct

```
struct number{
    int times;
    char numptr;
}numList[MAXNUM];
```

and create a function

```
void transform(int i, struct number *L){......}
```

pass the struct array to the function

```
transform(i, numList);
```

But why I can compile it  successfully by VC ,and somehow fail to compile it by gcc?
I use codeblocks and its compiler is gcc, part of its errors are here

```
warning: 'struct number' declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]|
warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want[enabled by default]|
warning: passing argument 2 of 'transform' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
note: expected 'struct number *' but argument is of type 'struct number *'|
error: conflicting types for 'transform'|
```

Comment: this is in fact a curious diagnostic of your compiler. my gcc (v4.6) eats this code without problem.

Comment: i think you're supposed to be defined in the double to wrote `transform(i, numList);` outside of function probably.

Comment: Try to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code with the version of your compiler. However this note looks strange: `expected 'struct number *' but argument is of type 'struct number *'`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the problem may simply be a matter of ordering.  Here are two examples of an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), one showing your problem and one not showing your problem.  The difference between the two is where the function declarations appear in the source — before or after the definition of `struct number`.

#### Clean Compiling

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXNUM = 3 };

struct number{
    int times;
    char numptr;
}numList[MAXNUM];

void transform(int i, struct number *L);

extern void function(void);

void function(void)
{
    int i = 3;
    transform(3, numList);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%c: %d\n", numList[j].numptr, numList[j].times);
}

$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c vc1.c
$
```

#### Warnings Included

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transform(int i, struct number *L);

extern void function(void);

enum { MAXNUM = 3 };

struct number{
    int times;
    char numptr;
}numList[MAXNUM];

void function(void)
{
    int i = 3;
    transform(3, numList);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%c: %d\n", numList[j].numptr, numList[j].times);
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ gcc -O3   -g      -std=c99   -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition     -c vc2.c
vc2.c:3:30: warning: ‘struct number’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
vc2.c:3:30: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
vc2.c: In function ‘function’:
vc2.c:17:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘transform’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
vc2.c:3:6: note: expected ‘struct number *’ but argument is of type ‘struct number *’
$
```

You could fix the second example by adding a line `struct number;` just after the `#include` (or, indeed, before it).  Or by moving the definition of `struct number` above the declaration of `void transform(int i, struct number *L);`.  It is easier to run into this problem if you have two source files, one defining the `transform()` function and separate one using it.  That's when you start using headers — they can be used to provide consistency checking between separate files.

Compiler: GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was perplexed by this prolem for a long time, but now I know where the mistake is.